# How can I remove object in one array from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have these lists:

```
List<Integer> numbersA=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> numbersB=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

"Numbers A" is [1,3,4,7,5,2] (There are no duplicate numbers)
and "Numbers B" is: [13,32,533,3,4,2]

So the method will remove "Numbers A" from "Numbers B",and "Numbers B" will be:
[13,32,533]

Comment: Traverse through one arraylist and try to remove items from the other.

Comment: Your example is wrong, you can't have a `List` with primitive types like `int`.

Comment: `List<int>` won't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method **RemoveAll**, here the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> numbersA = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> numbersB = new ArrayList<>();
numbersA.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2 }));
numbersB.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 13, 32, 533, 3, 4, 2 }));
System.out.println("A: " + numbersA);
System.out.println("B: " + numbersB);

numbersB.removeAll(numbersA);
System.out.println("B cleared: " + numbersB);
}
```

this will print

> A: [1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2]
>
> B: [13, 32, 533, 3, 4, 2]
>
> B cleared: [13, 32, 533]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c);` method of List. It will remove the common element.

```
numbersB.removeAll(numbersA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Java 8 version
```

**Version 1 Mutating the original Array**

```
Integer [] array1 = new Integer[]{1,3,4,7,5,2};
Integer [] array2 = new Integer[]{13,32,533,3,4,2};

List<Integer> numbersA=Arrays.asList(array1);
final List<Integer> numbersB=Arrays.asList(array2);

numbersA.stream().forEach(t->numbersB.remove(t));
```

**Version 1 using filter and returning new List**

```
Integer [] array1 = new Integer[]{1,3,4,7,5,2};
    Integer [] array2 = new Integer[]{13,32,533,3,4,2};

    List<Integer> numbersA=Arrays.asList(array1);
    final List<Integer> numbersB=Arrays.asList(array2);

   List<Integer> numbersA.stream().filter(t->numbersB.contains(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't really like your answer, first of all you don't need to create a List from an array to get the stream, and second you're changing state in the forEach when you could use filter and collect to another array, I think it would be much clearer/cleaner